# SVN "not a working copy"

Tags: svn

Ok ... so I wanted to upload something to an SVN server. How hard can that be?
Well, turns out I've been using windumb for too long.

First I am supposed to "clone" the folder to my computer, using

```
svn co --username USERNAME URL
```

Alright, so I

```
cd ~/.../0.SVN
svn co --username USERNAME URL
```

and get an

```
svn: OPTIONS from URL: 200 OK.
```

Next, I create a folder `~/.../0.SVN/someFolder`,
put some files into that folder and want to add it so I can commit it.

```
 svn add someFolder
```

And now it's giving me an

```
 "." is not a working copy
```

And I have no idea what's going wrong because I'm basically doing exactly what the instructions I was given are saying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that the URL was `http://svn.example.com/somewhere/somerepo`. Then `svn co http://svn.example.com/somewhere/somerepo` creates a subdirectory of the current directory called `somerepo`. That's where the svn checkout is located.

If you want to add more files to the svn repository, you need to put them under that `somerepo` directory.

```
cd somerepo
# create someFolder and put your new stuff there
svn add someFolder
svn commit
```

Use the command `ls` to see what files exist in a directory. Use `ls -A` to also see hidden files like the `.svn` subdirectory.

Use `svn info` to see what svn thinks about the current directory.

---

All this is assuming that the checkout was successful. If you ever see this message from svn:

```
svn: OPTIONS from http://svn.example.com/somewhere/somerepo: 200 OK
```

(or some other HTTP code: 403, 403, etc.)
that's subversion's way of telling you that it did not understand the response from the server. Common causes are:

- This is the wrong URL, the server at that URL is not a subversion server. Fix: type the correct URL.
- You did not authenticate successfully. Usually you get a 403 HTTP status in that case, but some servers reply with 404 or even 200 (which is supposed to mean success, but some servers are funny that way).

Comment: What if the svn co command does not create a subdirectory?

Comment: @User1291 Oh, I wasn't paying enough attention. Unfortunately for you, “OPTIONS from URL: 200 OK” is svn's way of telling you that something went wrong when parsing the response from the server. Usually this means that either what's on this URL is not a subversion server, or that you did not authenticate successfully. Try the same URL in an anonymous window in your browser and check that you authenticated in the same way.

Comment: You mean to tell me that "OK" actually means "something went wrong"? Whatever idiot coded these errors should be slapped hard. Anyway, I checked the directory in a browser and after complaining about its nonexistance, it turns out I was given an old one. :P Thanks for the help.

Comment: @User The web server says OK because it is serving some content. It's svn's fault for reporting that instead of saying "I don't understand”.